# Windows 10 hangs on logo sometimes with no spinning dots

Tags: boot, windows-10

Sometimes my PC will not boot it just hangs on the Windows 10 logo and no dots show below the logo. Also my HDD light is always solid when this is happening(I have a SSD by the way). To fix this I have to reboot my computer several times via the reset switch then eventually it will boot. It doesn't always hang on the logo just randomly as I can tell. Anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like windows is having a hard time reading the SSD. The next time you get your computer to boot sucessfully, open the cmd prompt as an admin (it's an option in <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>.)

type...
wmic + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
diskdrive get status + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If that shows an error, you've found the culprate. Your drive is dying. Otherwise I'd recommend reinstalling windows from an earlier backup when this wasn't an issue.

Comment: Thank you, I have done that and no errors were shown. Most of the time it boots just sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @haws1290 When it's so inconsistent it's hard to figure out exactly what the issue is. Your best bet is just to reinstall from your last backup, however I did just find this thread, which is probably a duplicate and has a much more through answer. http://superuser.com/questions/965692/windows-10-occasional-stuck-at-boot-before-spinning-dots?rq=1

Comment: Thank you I will restore from an earlier backup. Thank you for the other thread also.