# Windows restart takes an unreasonable amount of time. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I restart my laptop once in a while.  For whatever reason it can be stuck on the Restarting screen for 5 to 20 minutes.

What steps can I take to see why it takes such a long time?

Comment: Have you [enabled boot logging](https://superuser.com/a/965701/337631)?

Comment: Perhaps you restart to seldom? And every time you restart it is installing updates. Does it take that long to restart if you restart again?

Answer (score 0):

Some processes resist shutting down for a number of reasons.

- Since you only restart occasionally, there are maintenance tasks that could be running.

  - Windows performs [automatic disk optimization](https://winaero.com/blog/optimize-drives-schedule-windows-10/). This process takes a while, and interrupting it abruptly can damage the file structure.
  - [Windows update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/887012/why-you-may-be-prompted-to-restart-your-computer-after-you-install-a-s) may begin while restarting.
  - Antimalware applications may be performing a scheduled scan.
  - If, for security, you [clear the pagefile automatically](https://winaero.com/blog/clear-pagefile-shutdown-windows-10/), that slows shutdown.
  - If encryption is used, that may also take additional time to shut down.
- In addition, various types of malware may be running on your PC, and don't want to quit. E.G.

  - [Coin mining](https://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/cryptocurrency-mining-malware-2018-new-menace/) uses your machine to make money for others.
  - [Bots](https://us.norton.com/internetsecurity-malware-what-are-bots.html) can be sending spam from your PC.

First thing to do is make a thorough malware scan of your system.

Second, let any pending Windows maintenance finish. If you shut the system before it finishes, the maintenance will still be performed next time.

Third, [check the Windows Event Log](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/78335-read-shutdown-logs-event-viewer-windows.html) for processes that take a long time to shut down, i.e. that occur in the minutes after a shutdown is initialized.

Fourth, if a process takes a long time to close (it's "hung"), Windows can [force it to shut down in a timely manner](http://www.speed-up-pc.org/speed_up_windows/windows_shutdown.php) using the Registry. The keys below can be added and modified to set a limit on how long a process will be given before it is killed.

- `WaitToKillAppTimeout`
- `HungAppTimeout`
- `AutoEndTasks`
- `WaitToKillServiceTimeout`
- `LowLevelHooksTimeout`

**N.B.** Killing some critical processes this way might cause issues, so check first that it's not maintenance slowing *Restart*.